# MySQL Count(Distinct) returning one value

Tags: mysql

I have the following table below and I am trying to find each IID that has at least 2 or more same IID's and find the average of the stats. The MySQL statement is as follows:
**select count(distinct IID) as counted from rate;** but I get one field and it states a number of 15, the table is very small and only has 20 tuples. I am stuck and can't go any further than this.

```
UID| IID   | stats
-----------------
1  | 1     | 3
1  | 1     | 4
1  | 3     | 1
2  | 3     | 1
2  | 3     | 1
2  | 1     | 3
2  | 2     | 4
```

The result I would like to see is 
grouped by IID's if there is two or more and an average of stats. I have a feeling I have to group by IID and sum the stats and divide by amount of count.

```
IID   | stats
-----------------
1     | 3.5
3     | 1.5
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the results you are looking for.  For instance, how can an `IID` have "at least 2 or more same `IID`s?

Comment: I have updated to include what I would like to see as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want an average then just use `avg(stats)`. I couldn't see how to make the numbers match with your output so I thought perhaps you wanted a different divisor.

```
select sum(stats) / (count(distinct UID) * 1e) /* cast to float */
from rate
group by IID
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

That is most likely correct. Your  statement counts the number of distinct values in that column. For your case, you should use `group by` and `having`.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use group_by(IID) that will group your data according to IID then use where clause in it.

Answer (score 0):

The following query will return the average of `stats` for each `iid` that has more than one row:

```
select iid, avg(stats)
from table t
group by iid
having count(*) > 1;
```

This seems like a reasonable result, but the values would be:

```
1    3.33
3    1
```

I am not sure what calculation you have in mind for the results in your question.

Comment: How come the average is 3.33 and 1?

Comment: There are three rows in the sample data with `IID` = 1.  Their stats are 3, 3, and 4.  The average is 3.33.  There are three rows witih `IID` = 3, their stats are uniformly 1.  The average is 1.